# Navigation menu being hidden by jquery picture viewer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, menu

As you can kind of see in the image below, my menu is dropping down below my photo viewer.  The photo viewer is jquery and CSS.  The menu is a implemented as an asp Menu.  If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.  Thanks

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu"  StaticDisplayLevels="1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="5" DataSourceID="menu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">

div.menu
{
     padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     width:100%;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

div.menu ul.nav li
{
    display: inline;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #CC1111;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size:large;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #CC1111;
    color: #ffffff;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image: Dropdown getting hidden by image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use z-index. Give higher value for div.menu and give lower value for image.

See this: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Answer (score 1):

Give your menu a `z-index` value, such as

```
div.menu
{
     padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     width:100%;
     position: relative;
     z-index:100;
}
```

My assumption is that theres one being set for the picture viewer as well, so you need yours to be higher.

**[Reference](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/z-index/)**